# Javascript Array to Objects transformEmployeeData

Tags: javascript

Write a function called "transformEmployeeData" that transforms some employee data from one format to another.

The argument will look something like this:

```
 [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role','clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role','manager']]]
```

Given that input, the return value should look like this:

```
[
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role:'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role:'manager'}
]
```

**Note** that the input may have a different number of rows or different keys than the given sample.

For example, let's say the HR department adds a "t-shirtSize" field to each employee record. Your code should flexibly accommodate that.

**Starter Code:**

```
function transformEmployeeData(array) {}
```

Comment: How's that homework coming?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: We are here to help you solve your issue, not write code for you. Please show us what all you have tried

Comment: Why is most of your question formatted as code?

Answer (score 1):

For iterating through an array and passing each element through a modifying function, `.map` is usually the best method.

```
function transformData(data) {
  return data.map(function(a) {
    var obj = {};
    a.map(function(b) {
      obj[b[0]] = b[1];
    });
    return obj;
  })
}
```

This iterates through the array of array of key-value arrays, and for each array of key-value arrays, and it converts each array of key-value arrays into a key-value object (by iterating though each key-value array and setting the object's properties `obj[prop] = value` notation).

Wow. That was a mouthful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next function

```
var employedList = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role','clerk']],[['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role','manager']]]



function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  var tranformEmployeList = [];

  for(var i = 0; i< array.length; i++) {
    var tempData = {}
    for(var e = 0; e< array[i].length; e++) {
      tempData[array[i][e][0]] = array[i][e][1]
    }
    tranformEmployeList.push(tempData)
  }

  return tranformEmployeList
}


console.log(transformEmployeeData(employedList)) // =>  the console
```

[CODE EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNqzmO?editors=1010)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

This converts the array to the object.

Comment: Two inaccuracies: 1: JSON.stringify converts the argument to an *string*, not an *object*. 2: The array of key-value arrays isn't converted to JSON.